# zend framework 2 404 error occured

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i'm new to zend framework 2 and was trying to add the album module into ZF2's skelton application but getting
 A 404 error occurred
 Page not found.
 The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
my Album/config/module.config.php code  is

```
<?php
    return array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
            ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
             ),
         ),
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'album' => array(
                    //'type' => 'segment',
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        //'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                        //'route'       => '/:controller[.:formatter][/:id]',
                        'route' => '/album',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'formatter'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                             '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                            'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

and in Application/config/module.config.php i have added these lines:

```
'modules' => array(
        'Application',    
        'Album'
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
```

can anyone plz help me to correct the codes...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is within your Route-Configuration:

```
'defaults => array(
    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
    'controller'    => 'Album\Controller\Album',
)
```

With this you tell the Router to load the following class

```
Album\Controller\Album\Controller\Album
```

The `__NAMESPACE__` will be prepended to whatever you assign as `controller`. So you have two options:

1. Skip the `__NAMESPACE__`
2. Modify the `controller`

While this is completely up to you, personally I choose to skip the `__NAMESPACE__` since ultimately all we're doing is working with keys and with the way i understand things, keys are no classes and therefore shouldn't have a namespace :D

Answer (score 0):

You need little changes dude...nothing wrong with your code.

**NameSpace**

If You specify Namespace, you have to include only the controller name in routing:

```
'defaults' => array(
    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
    'controller' => 'Album' /* Not like this: 'Album\Controller\Album' */
    'action' => 'index',
),
```

**If no namespace included**

```
'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album' /* Include this */
    'action' => 'index',
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use configuration like Application module in ZendSkeletonApplication:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Album',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

You just add the following code:

```
'album' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[0-9]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Album',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

add this code to 'child-routes' key and after that you'll access to url: localhost/module[/:controller][/:action][/:id]. And now it's worked!